# Distribute items from a list of sub arrays to other sub arrays / works sometimes then randomly errors

Tags: arrays, algorithm, go, data-structures, maps

I have a program that creates a list of arrays. The first array is populated with values while the other arrays can either be empty or not. If it is empty, we take a value from the first array and move to an empty array. The goal is never to have an empty array in the list

```
Array      Values
    A1 -> V1, V2, V3, V4, V5 // add extra val to whatever is nxt in line
    A2  <------|----------| //add A1[0][1] and A1[0][4] since its extra
    A3  <----------|       //add A1[0][2]
    A4  <--------------|   //add A1[0][3]
```

Here is what I have. What I am confused about is that is it randomly getting index out of range while sometimes it will work, and I am sure there is a much more optimal and efficient way of doing this. I would love to see it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){

    //Create list of arrays
    something := []string{"first", "second", "third"}
    something2 := []string{""}
    something3 := []string{""}


    thisMap := make(map[int] []string, 0)


    //assign them
    thisMap[0] = something
    thisMap[1] = something2
    thisMap[2] = something3



    //loop through the maps
    for k, v := range thisMap{
        //if the key is great than 0
        if k > 0 {
            //loop through the array
            for _, items := range v {

                //if the item is empty
                if items == "" {
                    //we remove the empty string since we dont need it 
                    v = v[1:]
                    //append the k value from the first array to the k array
                    v = append(v, thisMap[0][k])

                    //We update the array and remove the item we just assigned from the initial array
                    thisMap[0] = append(thisMap[0][:k], thisMap[0][k+1:]...)

                }

            }
            //Assign the arrays back to the map
            thisMap[k] = v
        }

    }
    fmt.Println(thisMap)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems is at this line:

```
v = append(v, thisMap[0][k])
```

Here, you assyme that the lengths of `thisMap[0]` is at least k, which is false if for example `k` is 2 and `thisMap[0]` has only one element left.

Since the iteration on map key/value pairs happens in a random order, if you are lucky, the order will be 2, 1, 0, and everything will work well. If you are unlucky, you can get the out of range problem.

Instead of picking the element at position `k` from `thisMap[0]`, you should get either the first element, or the last, or a random element, but always take into account the current length of `thisMap[0]`.

My two cents about the organisation of the code:

- `thisMap[0]` and the other entries of the map clearly play different roles in your algorithm. So you should names your variables and organize your code to reflect this.  For example, you could write a function that takes a []string, and returns a map[int][]string, or maybe even a [][]string
- I think initializing the output lists with a single empty string inside, and remove it later is introducing un-necessary noise, you could initialize empty output lists. Also, I'm not sure the implementation on this of this part is correct !

Comment: thanks for the insight i looked passed the issue with the first append!